Bundle.getSerializable Deprecated in Android 33
Bundle.getSerializable(String) is deprecated in API 33.
Bundle.getSerializable(String, Class) is added in API 33.
Issue 1:
Existing code :
Object testObj= null;
testObj = arguments.getSerializable("Sample Text");

Changed to
Object testObj= null;
testObj= arguments.getSerializable("this", Object.class);


Error : 'getSerializable(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class)' in 'android.os.Bundle' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class<java.lang.Object>)'

Issue 2:
Map<String, Object> myArgs = (Map) bundle.getSerializable("Sample text");

Changed to
Map<String, Object> myArgs = (Map) bundle.getSerializable("Sample text", Map.class);

Error :

'getSerializable(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class)' in 'android.os.Bundle' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class<java.util.Map>)'

I am getting the errors as Object and Map are not Serializable type. How to resolve these type of issues.

We can use BundleCompat.getSerializable(...) for backward compatibility.
Issue 1:
Since Java Object is not Serializable, use the class you put into the bundle.
public class MyObject implements Serializable {
   // ...
}

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("myObject", new MyObject());

MyObject myObject = BundleCompat.getSerializable(bundle, "myObject", MyObject.class);

Issue 2:
Since Map is not Serializable, use HashMap.
HashMap<String, MyObject> args = new HashMap<>();
args.put("arg1", new MyObject("Hi"));
bundle.putSerializable("myArgs", args);

//noinspection unchecked
HashMap<String, MyObject> myArgs = (HashMap<String, MyObject>) BundleCompat.getSerializable(bundle, "myArgs", HashMap.class);

But Parcelable is recommended approach for data transfers in Android. And yes,  BundleCompat also supports Parcelable.
If you just want Java Object, use Serializable.
Object myObject = BundleCompat.getSerializable(bundle, "myObject", Serializable.class);


Thank for your reply. I have create the custom class and used in getSerializable() and no compiler error. In my requirement, getSerializableIe API is returning java.lang.Object type value, how to use the java.lang.Object class in getSerializableIe ()

@HydTech I updated the answer, please check it out. If it helps, please accept it as an answer, thanks.
